# Preferred way of checking nulls for defensive copies

Tags: java

Suppose I have the following method:

```
public void change(Map<String, String> map)
```

I would like to throw an exception if `map` is `null` and make a defensive copy if it's not.

Would this be preferred:

```
public void change(Map<String, String> map)
{
    Map<String, String> temp = null;

    synchronized (map) {
            if (map == null)
                throw new NullPointerException("map is null");
        temp = new HashMap<String, Object>(map);
}
```

or

```
public void change(Map<String, String> map)
    try {
        Map<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, Object>(map);
    } 
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new NullPointerException("map is null");
    }
```

or is there a better way? why and why not.

***EDITS***:

revised a few typos I had:

`properties` should be `map`

(String, Object) should be `(String, String)`

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't explicitly catch and re-throw NPE.  The line number should tell you what is null and only a developer can fix it. BTW: If you are going to check for `null` it should be before you attempt to synchronise on it. ;)

Comment: in the first code block, you're going to get an NPE if you try to synchronize on map and it's null.

Comment: Why is the map a `<String, String>` and its copy a `<String, Object>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well your first way will throw an exception if `map` is null not due to your code, but due to the `synchronized` block.

It's not really clear what you're trying to do given that in your second approach you're declaring a *local* variable, which will be pointless. Is the idea to set an instance variable, or to perform more work on the map after creating the copy?

You also need to know what's going to happen in terms of threading - you can't guarantee that everything will be synchronizing on the map reference itself. Personally I'd isolate threading from other concerns, and handle it more centrally. I'd write something like this, using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) for both calls:

```
public void change(Map<String, String> map)
{
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(map);
    Map<String, String> copy = Maps.newHashMap(map);
    // Use copy here
}
```

The `Maps.newHashMap` call uses type inference to avoid you having to state the type arguments as you would in a normal constructor call (unless you're using Java 7).

Comment: If checkNotNull throws an NPE, is it there just for clarity?

Comment: @Peter: In think case, just clarity - in other cases, making sure that the check occurs early, before any side-effects occur. (In non-exception cases it returns the value passed, so it's quite common to have `this.foo = Preconditions.checkNotNull(foo);` in a constructor.)

Comment: I think if you are using Guava anyways, Preconditions.checkNotNull is quite handy. But there are even better ways to handle null, see e.g. http://www.slideshare.net/Stephan.Schmidt/better-strategies-for-null-handling-in-java or my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with neither.

Your first example doesn't do much if there's no chance of multithreading. (Is properties thread safe?)

Your second example is poor because it's using exceptions to define program flow when it's so easily avoided. Personally, I would use

```
public void change(Map<String,String> map) {
    if(map == null) throw new NullPointerException("map is null");
    Map<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>(map);
    // continue with temp...
}
```

Comment: +1: Where did `properties` come from? Perhaps it should be a `Map<String, String>` as well.

Comment: @Peter it appears properties has been edited out of the original within the grace period. :) And I agree, I would make this `<String,String>` unless I have some very specific need to be able to map to something other String. And even if I do, that's probably indicative of a bigger problem.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely the first way, but without the `synchronized` (unless you're really sure that you need it); if you are able to easily and reliably predict whether an exception will be thrown, it is more readable (and slightly more efficient) to test that condition than using a try/catch. However, you should never throw `NullPointerException`s yourself - throw [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) instead.

Comment: True. ++ to the catch on IllegalArgumentException. Makes more sense.

Comment: Except that I believe Effective Java suggests using NullPointerException. Oh for .NET's ArgumentNullException...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Interesting; I wasn't aware of that. What's their argument(!) for doing that, instead of reserving `NullPointerException` for actual null pointer dereferencing?

Comment: @Aasmund: I can't remember offhand and unfortunately don't have a copy handy. However, if you look at the docs it seems reasonable: "Applications should throw instances of this class to indicate other illegal uses of the null object" and "Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required."

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7, you can use [Objects.requireNonNull](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull%28T,%20java.lang.String%29) to check if a reference is not `null` and throw a NPE if it is.

```
public static void change(Map<String, String> map){
    Objects.requireNonNull(map, "map should not be null");
    Map<String, Object> copy = new HashMap<>(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
public void change(/*NonNull*/ Map<String, String> map) {
  if (map == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter must be nonnull"); 
  };
  //...
}
```

Since it's an exported method, clients should get an exception on their abstraction level, so IllegalArgumentException is better than NPE.

The comment `/*NonNull*/` can be checked already **at compile-time** using the nullness checker from the [(pluggable type-)checker framework](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/). Something similar is also possible via Findbugs, IDEA or Netbeans, but their checks are not sound, i.e. they can have false positives. Doing a programmatic nullness check still makes sense, because a client might not make the complie-time nullness checks (i.e. use the checker framework/Findbugs/IDEA/Netbeans/...).